# Should data tables have separate columns for each object field?

Tags: tables, data-tables

Say you have an object that is referenced by both an ID and a Name (both unique). The object also has a label that is more user friendly that is used though out the site. Should a grid show both the name and label as separate columns in a CRUD grid? The fields are separate in all the dialogs for the CRUD of the object.

Comment: Do you have a rough mock that you can show us to be more specific? Also, is the human friendly name being created /editing by a user, or is it auto-generated and uneditable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keep them separate - It simplifies that aspect of the UI**

Breaking out these elements, making those attributes more granularly accessible, makes things easier to parse in general.

Combining these attributes into a single value decreases the flexibility and utility of each.

In the example below, with the second (bottom) wireframe, it would be easier to provide a featured that allowed filtering or searching on the ID field, than it would in the first wireframe.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQCLlT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's better to have the name and label in separate columns. Since it is CRUD page it would be easy to perform actions. For example, in future, you want to change the rename/update label it would be easy to perform edit/update name in that particular column which is a tedious task when name and label are combined.